# jQuery Post, PHP and MySQL Returning Data

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I want to use jQuery to pull information from my database when I click a button.

i've managed to get console.log to display the following

> [Object { id="16", user_to="Obadiah Stane", user_delivery_add1="The Lanesborough"}]

But I cant figure out how to pull each value for use in a Form.

Could someone help?

jQuery

```
$.post('/assets/inc/get-delivery-details.php', qString, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('.addAddressDialog').html(json);   
    }, "json");
```

PHP

```
    $q = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user_delivery WHERE id = '$selectedID'";
$sql = mysql_query($q);

$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $results[] = array(
      'id' => $row['id'],
      'user_to' => $row['user_to'],
      'user_delivery_add1' => $row['user_delivery_add1']
   );
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $.post('/assets/inc/get-delivery-details.php', qString, function (data) {

        //var json = $.parseJSON(data); // don't need this line, because you've
                                        // already set dataType json as fourth 
                                        // arguments of $.post()

        // To get values
        alert(data[0].id);
        alert(data[0].user_to); // so on

        // To set above values to a form fields
        // just an example, don't know your form markup

        $('input[name=id]').val(data[0].id);  // so on

    }, "json");
```

Comment: This says in console log that 'json is null'

Comment: THANK YOU!! I'll accept it later as I'm away offline now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$('.addAddressDialog').html(json.id);` will output `16` in your example.

After parsing the variable json, it becomes an object.